# Issue with bipolar to unipolar opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, voltage-measurement, differential, bipolar

i want to measure ac voltage.For that i need to shift an ac differential voltage (+1.23/-1.23 across R20) to 0v - 2.5v range for a unipolar adc.The R1,R21,R22 divides the voltage and gives +/-1.23v across R20. The second part of
the circuit (opamp summing) is to shift this to 0-2.5v range. The V5 is an external voltage reference.The simulation shows that this external voltage reference (for opamp circuit) is effecting the voltage drop at R20, which is now between -0.47v to 1.23v.So the opamp output is also wrong, 0.77v to 2.5v (instead of 0-2.5v).How can i solve this? You can assume an ideal opamp.

PS: I am a software engineer, don't have deep understanding in electronics/circuits.

[image: opamp circuit]

Comment: C2 has shorted legs. It goes from ground to ground. - If you are trying to measure the mains voltage, then make sure you are not touching any of the connections with your hands.

Comment: If you use this configuration the voltage across R20 will be affected by the reference, so take that into account in your calculations. Or use a negative reference voltage rather than positive and apply it to the inverting input through a resistor. This circuit is rather dangerous- stick to simulations for the time being.

Comment: @HarrySvensson..  Ya.I will be carefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: First I have to point out this circuit is extremely dangerous. Applying high voltage lines directly to low voltage circuitry is generally a bad idea. Further, should the line connection be reversed you will have the full main voltage available on the ground of this circuit.**

That said, the issue with the use of the type of summing amplifier you have chosen is that it requires the input impedance to be very low if not zero for total accuracy.

Because the resistors you have chosen are the same order of magnitude as the resistor divider bottom value, it effectively changes the resistor divider equation. That is, what you now have is this....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpS3oV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can improve this situation by significantly increasing the resistors around the op-amp so that the effect of their impact on the divider is less than your required accuracy. In this instance I would suggest changing R3, R4, R18 and R19 to 330k resistors.

Ultimately to completely remove the effect of the op-amp from the divider you would need to add a voltage-follower op-amp between the divider and the summing amplifier to decouple the two. However, in order to do so you will need a negative power rail.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgG5Qz.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I don't need very high accuracy and don't have negative rail.I will use 330k range resistors..

Comment: @PradulMT "don't have negative rail" yes, I suspected that.

Comment: Some more doubts on this.The system will work the same way even if i remove the GND connection to the neutral line, right???

Comment: The (+) voltage on the opamp will be (Vref/2 + upper volatage on R20/2). And the (-) voltage on the opamp will be (Vout/2+ bottom voltage/2). So on equating Vout will be (Vref + voltage diff on R20)

Comment: The input common mode voltage range is Vcc-1.5, and i am using 5v supply. So i can't do this, because the neutral may go up to 10v or more..right? @SpehroPefhany

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would use another method, I would use a small capacitance capacitor to drop the voltage rather than 1 MΩ. Then I'd center it in the middle of what I'm interested in, which is 2.5 V in this case. Then I buffer the signal so I don't mess with it and then I finish it off with another op-amp that undo what the leftmost capacitor did, integrator/deriving wise.

[image]

Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.0000010000000000000002+45.7144713268909+50+5+50%0Ac+864+272+800+272+0+1e-9+71.15937201567078%0Ag+864+336+864+352+0%0AR+688+272+656+272+0+1+50+205+0+0+0.5%0Ar+864+272+864+336+0+10000%0Aa+912+256+1008+256+0+5+0+1000000+1.1969096644870483+1.1969216335836932%0Ar+864+272+864+208+0+10000%0AR+864+208+864+176+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ac+1104+208+1200+208+0+4.7000000000000004e-8+-0.8705247945578094%0Aw+1104+256+1104+208+0%0Ar+1008+256+1104+256+0+10000%0Aw+1200+208+1200+272+0%0Aw+1104+208+1104+160+0%0Ar+1104+160+1200+160+0+1000000%0Aw+1200+160+1200+208+0%0Aw+864+272+912+272+0%0Aw+912+240+912+208+0%0Aw+912+208+1008+208+0%0Aw+1008+208+1008+256+0%0Aa+1104+272+1200+272+0+15+-15+1000000+2.4999662950891035+2.5%0Ar+1104+288+1104+352+0+10000%0Ag+1104+352+1104+368+0%0AR+1024+288+992+288+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+1024+288+1104+288+0+10000%0Av+688+272+768+272+0+3+2500+20+0+0+0.5%0Ax+617+219+688+222+4+24+Mains%0Ax+696+320+764+323+4+24+Noise%0Aw+768+272+800+272+0%0Ax+1175+323+1257+326+4+24+Output%0Ao+26+64+0+4354+320+0.000390625+0+2+26+3%0Ao+14+16+0+4355+20+0.00009765625+1+2+14+3%0Ao+10+64+0+4354+10+0.0001953125+2+2+10+3%0A) if you want to mess around with the circuit.

- The left signal is the voltage in the node between the noise and the 1 nF capacitor.
- The middle signal is the voltage in the node marked blue in the schematic.
- The right signal is the output which is 180 phase shifted, can be solved in software `Output = 5-Output;` or by adding an inverting op-amp.

The rightmost op-amp is an integrator, this means that if the input has any DC voltage at all, any what so ever, even the slightest nano volt, then they will accumulate and your output will start to drift. What you want is to not drift, and that is what the 1 MΩ resistor assists with. It will help your signal to remove any DC-value if they ever come into your system. Or if you put energy into the system and never take it out, say touch either connections with your fingers, then that will also give you an offset of your reading, and the 1 MΩ takes care of that. It removes drift.

---

If you want you can just feed the signal at the blue node straight into your MCU and integrate it in software, this way you get rid of the two op-amps, but on the software side you have to integrate and make sure you are sampling at at least 1 kHz if you want *reasonably* good quality on your reading. The higher the frequency the better the resolution (duh). **You will only need 3 components.**

```
Output+= V_at_blue_node - 2.5;
```

But this will drift, which can be solved by applying a "resistor" in software like this:

```
Output+= V_at_blue_node - 2.5;
Output = (Output-2.5)*0.99999+2.5;
```

Or simply

```
Output = (Output-2.5)*0.99999+V_at_blue_node;
```

---

You might want to choose the amplitude of the output "ripple" from the 1 nF and the 2 10 kΩ network.

Here's a formula for selecting R knowing the amplitude of the mains sine wave and the capacitance.

\$R=\frac{2V_{ripple}}{V_{mains}2\pi fC}\$

So say you want a sine wave with an amplitude of 205 V to give you a sine wave with a 2 V amplitude. This way you will be able to see voltages that are 25% larger (~250 V => 500 V peak to peak). Let's also say you are using a 1 nF capacitor.

\$R=\frac{2×2}{205×2\pi ×50×1×10^{-9}}=62109.246 \approx 62.1kΩ\$

[image]

Comment: +1 Does "small capacitor" and 410V go in the same sentence ;) Also worried user thinks he can meet the creepage/clearance requirements with some of those SMT caps that are rated up there but plainly can't actually be used at those voltages.

Comment: @Trevor_G Oh, yeah true, I got a 3.3 µF rated for 400 V and it's as big as my thumb. Not small at all. Oh well, I changed my answer so it says small capacitance, like 1 nF. - Yeah there might be some clearance issues... oh well, let's hope OP knows what he does.